# How To Change Specific Value of All Users In Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Database;

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsWY6.png)

I want to make the `highestScore` of all users 0. How can i do this?

Edit: I solved this w/Hasnain Sabir

```
final DatabaseReference mDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        mDBRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<String> userScores = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    userScores.add(userSnapshot.getKey());
                }

                for (int i = 0;i < userScores.size();i++){
                    mDBRef.child(userScores.get(i)).child("highestScore").setValue("0");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Any attempt from your end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update it by getting all the user and then update the specific property of user object .  `

```
val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference(USER)
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val user = snapshot.getValue(USER::class.java)!!
                val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                hashMap["highestScore"] = 0
                snapshot.ref.updateChildren(hashMap)
            
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Thanks this is worked to me. But In my original database, users are not registered with user names such as user1, user2, user3, user4 as here. Recorded according to Uid. Is there a way to get the Uid of all users? It's only a matter of time before I solve the problem

Comment: yes you can get the uid. with htelp of snapshot value. e.d  userId = snapshot.getKey() or getUId.